# Code to output individual fields in a Theme view

Tags: views, theming

I know this question seems to have been half answered a few times but I'm finding it difficult to apply a working solution. I have created a new theme from scratch to use for a view I have created. I can get the view content to display in the Theme by using:

> print render($page['content']);

However because of the complexity of my theme layout I need to display the fields in the view individually.

I understand that I need to create a file in the theme folder called something like:
views-view-field--viewname.tpl.php and add some php, then add some code to this but I just can't seem to find the correct code that is needed plus the correct syntax I add to the theme page.tpl.php to show the individual fields. Could anyone please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, 
I sorted this out. I didn't quite understand that I need to make layout changes in the appropriately named views-view-fields--viewname.tpl.php. I was hoping to just add some php to the page.tpl.php theme file I have developed for my views.

It's quite a learning curve with Drupal!